# Reactjs: How to add dataset dynamically in bar chart

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, charts, dataset, react-chartjs

I am using react chart js. iI had added bar chart in my page, my chart data is:

```
const data = {
          labels: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
          datasets: [
            {
              backgroundColor: '#db3eb1',
              data: [7, 8, 3],
            },
            {
              backgroundColor: '#db3eb1',
              data: [0, 9, 7],
            },
            {
              backgroundColor: '#db3eb1',
              data: [0, 10, 12],
            },
          ],
        };
```

Then I try to change this data into dynamically but it not working properly. The
dynamic data is:

```
[{"backgroundColor":"#db3eb1","data":[1.119]},
{"backgroundColor":"#db3eb1","data":[1.103]},    
{"backgroundColor":"#db3eb1","data":[1.105]},    
{"backgroundColor":"#db3eb1","data":[1.096]},
{"backgroundColor":"#db3eb1","data":[1.22,1.097]},
{"backgroundColor":"#db3eb1","data":[1.092]}]
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: how are you changing it?

Comment: @azium thank u for ur reply i changing through the map function `const datasetArray = map(barChartArray, el => ({
        backgroundColor: '#db3eb1',
        data: el
    }));`

Comment: `barChartArray` list of data like my dynamic `data`

Comment: map usage is like this :  `barChartArray.map(el => ({ ...`

Comment: i am using lodash